# Can't save data to load it after game was closed (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

I want to save values of some variables. I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103459/cant-save-data-to-file-and-then-load-it-in-unity3d) to save it to file, but it doesn't work. So now I try it in another way. But it don't save data too...  If I start simulation i Unity, change values of variables, stop simulation and then start it again, I have old values of the variables..

```
    void OnEnable()
    {        
        LoadFromFile();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {        
        SaveToFile();
    }

    public void SaveToFile()
    {
        GameObject gameManagerObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GAMEMANAGER");
        GAMEMANAGER gameManager = gameManagerObject.GetComponent<GAMEMANAGER>();
        IndicatorsInfo indicatorsInfo = new IndicatorsInfo();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("my_setting", indicatorsInfo.walkSpeedTemfFile);
    }

    public void LoadFromFile()
    {
        GameObject gameManagerObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GAMEMANAGER");
        GAMEMANAGER gameManager = gameManagerObject.GetComponent<GAMEMANAGER>();

        gameManager.walkSpeedTemp = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("my_setting");
    }

    [Serializable]
    class IndicatorsInfo
    {
        public float walkSpeedTemfFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> IndicatorsInfo indicatorsInfo = new IndicatorsInfo();
> PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("my_setting", indicatorsInfo.walkSpeedTemfFile);
> ```

You are creating a **new** *instance* of `IndicatorsInfo` when you use the `new` keyword. You saved `indicatorsInfo.walkSpeedTemfFile` from that **new** instance **without** assigning a **value** to the new `indicatorsInfo` you created.

Maybe what you are trying to do is save the value from the **Editor**?

```
GameObject gameManagerObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GAMEMANAGER");
GAMEMANAGER gameManager = gameManagerObject.GetComponent<GAMEMANAGER>();
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("my_setting", gameManager.walkSpeedTemp);
```