# Save files in downloads folder using Unity - Windows Phone 10

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

Can anyone tell me how can I save files in the Downloads folder for Windows Phone using Unity?

Comment: The short answer is: **just forget it**.  It's just not what Unity is for.  You can't do it and it will never really work.  Consider this ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36236745/294884

Comment: if someone have this problem or try to do I made I please check this plugin it's great https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/54715