# How to reload Unity resources populated by XML

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, dynamic

I am populating a few elements like a ScrollView with data from a few XML files. By clicking a button, the most recent files are being fetched from a server.
I am trying to display them directly in the GUI, but I always have to restart the application in order to see the last downloaded version.
Downloading and writing works properly.

Here's some code:

First the downloading/updating process

```c#
public bool update() {
    try {
        // Download + Save
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "");
        wc.DownloadFile(_address_employeesXML, _filePathToXMLImport + "/employees.xml");

        XMLReader test = new XMLReader(logController);
        test.readXMLFiles(); 
        Debug.Log("Update successful");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Error",  e.Message, "OK");
        #endif
        XMLReader test = new XMLReader(logController);
        //test.readXMLFiles();
        Debug.LogException(e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

then the read process:

```c#
    public bool readEmployees()
{
    string pathToEmployeeXML = _filePathToXMLImport + "/employees.xml";
    if (File.Exists(pathToEmployeeXML))
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(pathToEmployeeXML))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Only detect start elements.
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    switch(reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "employee":

                            XmlReader inner = reader.ReadSubtree();

                            inner.ReadToDescendant("firstName");
                            string firstName = inner.ReadElementString();
                            inner.ReadToDescendant("lastName");
                            string lastName = inner.ReadElementString();

                            generateEmployee(firstName, lastName);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I found this thread:
[Reloading XML asset in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222700/reloading-xml-asset-in-unity)
Which unfortunately is not really solving my problem.

I also tried using AssetDatabase.Refresh, but didn't really find out how to implement it to be honest.

EDIT:

So now I changed it up to use File.IO and to load the files async. I still need to restart the app to see the changes though.

```c#
public class XMLController : MonoBehaviour {

public MessageLogsController logController;
public ApplicationStateSaver saver;

const string _address = "ftp://127.0.0.1:2121/";
const string _address_maintenancePlansXML = _address + "maintenancePlans.xml";
const string _address_employeesXML = _address + "employees.xml";
const string _address_materialsXML = _address + "materials.xml";
const string _address_machinesXML = _address + "machines.xml";
const string maintenancePlans = "maintenancePlans";
const string employees = "employees";
const string materials = "materials";
const string machines = "machines";
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    XMLReader XMLReader = new XMLReader(logController);

    StartCoroutine(GetXML(_address_maintenancePlansXML, maintenancePlans));
    StartCoroutine(GetXML(_address_employeesXML, employees));
    StartCoroutine(GetXML(_address_materialsXML, materials));
    StartCoroutine(GetXML(_address_machinesXML, machines));

    XMLReader.readXMLFiles();
    saver.Initialize();
}

public void WriteInformationToXML()
{
    XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter();
    writer.writeXML();

}

IEnumerator GetXML(string link, string file_name) {
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(link);

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    Debug.Log("Success");

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else {
        // Show results as text
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

        string savePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}.xml", Application.persistentDataPath + "/Files/XML/Import/", file_name);        
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(savePath, www.downloadHandler.text);
        Debug.Log("Files written");

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? What did you try? How can we solve your problem without more informations?

Comment: I added some code. I though I'm just missing out on an existing function, which helps reloading a canvas/certain assets without restarting the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was moving the code I mentioned above to the Controller class that is responsible for the StartView.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather make the whole process async in order to not block the mainthread using [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) for the download.

Actually you don't really have to write to the file and read it in again ... you could directly use the downloaded `string` and pass it to an [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer) (you have to implement a class representing the xml layout - see [Saving and Loading Data: XmlSerializer](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer)).

If you still need/want to write I would write to [`Application.persitentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) and read/write the file using a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.writeasync)

```c#
public void update(Action<bool> success)  
{
    StartCoroutine(UpdateRoutine(onSuccess)); 
}

private string authenticate(string username, string password) 
{
    string auth = username + ":" + password;
    auth = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(auth));
    auth = "Basic " + auth;
    return auth; 
}  

private IEnumerator UpdateRoutine (Action<bool> onSuccess) 
{   
    using(var www = UnityWebRequest.Get(_address_employeesXML)
    {
        string authorization = authenticate("YourUserName", "YourPassWord");
        www.SetRequestHeader("AUTHORIZATION", authorization);

        yield return www.SendRequest();

        if(www.error)
        {
             success?.Invoke(false);
        } 
        else
        {
            // you could ofcourse simply use the returned filecontent now like
            var xml = www.downloadHandler.text;

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YOURDATA_CLASS));

            var dataClass = (YOURDATA_CLASS) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xml);
            success?.Invoke(true);


            // However if you prefer to write the file 
            WriteFile(xml, success);
        }
    }
}

// Usually async void is bad
// but with a callback its fine
private async void WriteFile(string xml, Action<bool> success)
{ 
    try
    {
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

        using(var file = File.Open(Path.Combine(_filePathToXMLImport, "employees.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            await file.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.length);

            success?.Invoke();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        success?.Invoke(false);
    }
}
```

then the read process:

```c#
public void ReadFile(Action<bool> success)
{
    using(var file = File.Open(Path.Combine(_filePathToXMLImport, "employees.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        var data = new byte[(int)file.length];
        await file.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.length);

        var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Data);

        var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer(typeof(YOURDATA_CLASS));

        var dataClass = (YOURDATA_CLASS) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xml);
        success?.Invoke(true);
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented the async fetching process. I am also writing to Application.persitentDataPath, but unfortunately I still need to restart the App in order to update the Assets.

Comment: your code worked perfectly, I just executed it from the false point.