# Can't perform IO in Unity Android build

Tags: android, file-io, unity-game-engine

So there is this game where I am using File I/O to store game data like high score and all that. It works fine in windows pc build(.exe) but I cant load the high score on android app.

I am just using a simple file name that gets created(if not exist) in the executable directory but same code doesn't seems to be working with android.

Is there a catch between working directories of android and windows pc? Please help..

```
string dataFile = Constants.GameDataFilePath;

gameDataFile = File.Open(dataFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                       FileAccess.Read,
                                       FileShare.None);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to save large amount of data locally in unity3D android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936710/best-way-to-save-large-amount-of-data-locally-in-unity3d-android)

Comment: you MUST use Application.persistentDataPath

Comment: Thanks @Joe...Will try that

Comment: But just to save game data, I'd prefer [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

Comment: @Thanks Joe..`Application.persistentDataPath` did the trick..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of what Joe said, `Application.persistentDataPath+"filename.extension"`, you should also go to **Build Settings**->select Android, click **Player Settings** and change **Write Access** from **Internal Only** to **External (SD)**. Sometimes, that seems to be a problem if you don't do it.