# Json to Dictionary C# Unity

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to change a JSONNode into a Dictionnary. I've been searching for hours for a solution. I know that JsonUtilities doesn't work with Dictionaries. Everything I try gives `test4 = null` with no errors.

```
JSONNode test1 = JSON.Parse(customData);

//customData is :"{\"ItemClass\":\"S\",\"Type\":\"Band\",\"Stats\":[{\"HP\":\"100\",\"Atk\":\"50\",\"Def\":\"25\",\"Crit\":\"10\"}]}"

               
JSONArray test2 = test1["Stats"].AsArray;

               
JSONNode  test3 = test2[0];
```

TEST4 always gives me a null, I tried changing test3 into an Object or string as well. Here are some of the stuff I tried:

```
var test4 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(test3);

var test4 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, int>>>(test3);

var test4 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>(test3);

var test4 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>(test3);
```

I'm trying to reach the Dictionaries that are in the picture below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JWLB.png

I'm sure I'm missing something super simple....

Thanks

Comment: this answer shows precisely how to move json to Dictionary in Unity https://stackoverflow.com/a/38535392/294884

Comment: Instead of directly serializing a dictionary then deserializing it, I suggest you to create list for both keys and values. When you want to use dictionary from JSON, add lists to an empty dictionary.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa I would suggest the opposite and rather directly use `Dictionary` which is fully supported by `Newtonsoft .Net JSON`

Comment: Isn't there a way to get to the dictionary in test3 (like in the picture) ? The examples in the link provided uses classes were as my example, there isn't really classes....maybe I'm not getting something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would rather use the proper data structure representation of your json (e.g. using [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com))

```
[Serializable]
public class Root    
{
    public string ItemClass; 
    public string Type; 
    public List<Dictionary<string,string>>; 
}
```

And then do

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString); 

foreach(var stat in root.Stats)
{
    foreach(var kvp in stat)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{kvp.Key}:{kvp.Value}");
    } 
}
```

Or alternatively not even use a `Dictionary` but directly a class like

```
[Serializable]
public class Stat
{
    public string HP; 
    public string Atk; 
    public string Def; 
    public string Crit; 
}

[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    public string ItemClass; 
    public string Type; 
    public List<Stat> Stats; 
}
```

Then you could either use

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

or also built-in

```
var root = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(jsonString);
```

and then do e.g.

```
foreach(var stat in root.Stats)
{
    Debug.Log($"HP:{stat.HP}, Ark:{stat.Atk}, Def:{stat.Def}, Crit:{stat.Crit}");
}
```

---

*Note: typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*