# C# Serialization Woes - Int Array not saving/returning correctly

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

I was hoping some one could enlighten me on what I am doing wrong, and the best way to correct it (or point me to a link that does).

I have the below code/classes I am using to serialize my data using a BinaryFormatter. For some reason the first int (Corners) in the TileData class is deserializing back as 255 all the time. I have verified that the data is saved in the structure correctly before serialization so some where between the serialization and deserialization something is happening with the data, and I'm unsure why or how to check which end it is.

Any thoughts?

```
[Serializable]
public class GameSaveData
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly int[] LevelSettings;
    public readonly int[] GTime;
    public readonly ChunkData[] Data; 

    public GameSaveData(string _name, int[] _settings, int[] _time, ChunkData[] _chunks)
    {
        Name = _name;
        LevelSettings = _settings;
        GTime = _time;
        Data = _chunks;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class TileData
{
    public readonly int Corners;
    public readonly int TypeID;
    public readonly int[] FloorSpecs; // 0 -- Floor Missing, 1 - Floor Type ID, 2 -- SubFloor Type

    public TileData(int _c, int _t, int[] _floorSpecs)
    {
        Corners = _c;
        TypeID = _t;
        FloorSpecs = _floorSpecs;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ChunkData
{
    public readonly int[] Position;
    public readonly TileData[] Data;

    public ChunkData(Vector3 _pos, TileData[] _data)
    {
        Position = new int[] { (int)_pos.x, (int)_pos.y, (int)_pos.z };
        Data = _data;
    }
}
```

Comment: would you like to post a picture of magical wand which you are using for serialization?

Comment: If you read the above I told you. I use the C# BinaryFormatter. Simply BinaryFormatter.Serialize() function.

Comment: Tried no dice, all the TileData.Corners deserialize into 255 for whatever reason.

Comment: Well, a piece of code that you are using for serialization would be helpful to get to problem.

Comment: Bolierplate BinaryFormatter.Serialize(FileStream,Class) code. REALLY hard to screw that part up, and the fact that SOMETHING is serializing and deserializing without error tells me (and apparently most everyone else) there is a data/structure issue being passed to the serializer. I believe I have found a work around simply implementing my own BinaryWriter/BinaryReader functions in the class and creating the file without the formatters help. It will greatly improve performance as well from what my searching has found. Thanks for the continued interest on the matter though, appreciate it.

Comment: In Unity3D never use the "serialization" for any reason.  It is basically broken and does not work.  They aim to fix it around Unity7.  So that's that.  Forget it.  Note that it is incredibly easy to just save some values using **Player.Prefs**.

Comment: Player.Prefs are disgusting and vile for almost any "serialization" purpose. Player.Prefs saves to the registry. I'm not going to dump a 30mb save file in a users registry. I'd rather just dump Unity and write an engine from bottom up for the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A serizable Class must be a simple container <del>with a parameterless constructor</del> (only at Xml Serialization).

Have a look at [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C).

Something like this

```
[Serializable]
public class GameSaveData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] LevelSettings { get; set; }
    public int[] GTime { get; set; }
    public ChunkData[] Data { get; set; }

    private GameSaveData() 
    {
        // parameter less constrctor
    }

    public GameSaveData(string _name, int[] _settings, int[] _time, ChunkData[] _chunks)
    {
        Name = _name;
        LevelSettings = _settings;
        GTime = _time;
        Data = _chunks;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class TileData
{
    public int Corners { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public int[] FloorSpecs { get; set; } // 0 -- Floor Missing, 1 - Floor Type ID, 2 -- SubFloor Type

    public TileData()
    {
        // parameter less constrctor            
    }

    public TileData(int _c, int _t, int[] _floorSpecs)
    {
        Corners = _c;
        TypeID = _t;
        FloorSpecs = _floorSpecs;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ChunkData
{
    public readonly int[] Position { get; set; }
    public readonly TileData[] Data { get; set; }

    public ChunkData()
    {
        // parameter less constrctor                        
    }

    public ChunkData(Vector3 _pos, TileData[] _data)
    {
        Position = new int[] { (int)_pos.x, (int)_pos.y, (int)_pos.z };
        Data = _data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the above for all the classes shown and the results are the same. Thanks for the input thought always willing to try something.

Comment: While this might work, please bear in mind that this is a limitation of `XmlSerializer`. Note that BinaryFormatter not `BinaryFormatter`. @Pysassin Just use Json like Mihai mentioned until this is fixed in Unity.

Comment: None of the information being passed in these classes or the classes themselves inherit anything via Unity structure, they are all .NET structures. Why do you think Unity is causing this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the additional links @Smartis, I may have to try and just implement the ISerializable interface and see if that clears things up.

Comment: This is a staggering waste of time and will never work.  If (incredibly) you have more data than you can easily save using PlayerPrefs, just do this ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/35941579/294884

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this, but doesn't the fact that the variables are marked as readonly prevent proper deserialization?

And why not use the JsonUtility class available in Unity? After all, Json is more widely available.

Comment: Changed class to struct and removed readonly and all the cominbations of the two and it still happens. The position int array is saving correctly so I am wondering if it is having issues serializing the TileData class while in the array.

Not using JSON because as I understood what I have read with it is it produces human readable save files which I currently do not desire.

Comment: JSON does do that, however I believe Unity encrypts those files upon building the app.

Comment: @Pysassin I second using Json. I think there is a problem with `BinaryFormatter` in Unity. There is something called encryption. You can encrypt the json string then save it. Google "C# string encryption".

Comment: Thanks, may also look at manual writing the Binary file instead of using BinaryFormatter as it takes excessively long time to load inside of Unity.