# file streamer crashes unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, filestream

I am trying to save data for my app I am using this code:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/inventorySave.gd"); 
bf.Serialize(file, toSave);
file.Close();
```

I also tried this code:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.persistentDataPath + "/inventorySave.txt");
sw.WriteLine(toSave);
print("wrote line" + toSave);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

But none of them seem to work (my unity crashes and I don’t get any errors in console). Saving is called inside a for loop, and I am trying to save string with less then 8 characters the code can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z526c8r03ayyy0n/code.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Are you doing this inside a try-catch block? Also, you should do StreamWriter inside of a using block, then there's no need to explicitly flush/close.

Comment: yes it is inside try catch, and it is looped 32 times, can loop make it crash?

Comment: That could.. yes. If your computer isn't fast enough or you're doing a lot. 32 times seems like a lot.

Comment: **DO NOT USE 'STREAM WRITER' FOR ANY REASON**  This is an endless confusion in Unity.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35941579/294884

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to save large amount of data locally in unity3D android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936710/best-way-to-save-large-amount-of-data-locally-in-unity3d-android)

Comment: Well what should u use?

Comment: but i am saving string withh 8 letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have found somewhere in your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.Length ; i++)
            {
                print("inside while class");
                switch (int.Parse(numbers[i--].ToString()))
                {
                    case 0:
                        finalString[i--] = "a".ToString(); break;
                    case 1:
                        finalString[i--] = "b".ToString(); break;
                    case 2:
                        finalString[i--] = "c".ToString(); break;
                    case 3:
                        finalString[0] = "d".ToString(); break;
                    case 4:
                        finalString[i--] = "e".ToString(); break;
                    case 5:
                        finalString[i--] = "f".ToString(); break;
                    case 6:
                        finalString[i--] = "g".ToString(); break;
                    case 7:
                        finalString[i--] = "h".ToString(); break;
                    case 8:
                        finalString[i--] = "i".ToString(); break;
                    case 9:
                        finalString[i--] = "j".ToString(); break;
                }

                i++;
```

In every iteration, this is what happens to variable `i`:

1. `int i = 0; // in start of for loop i is "0".`
2. `switch (int.Parse(numbers[i--].ToString()))  // i = -1 here`
3. `finalString[i--] = "a".ToString(); break; // in any of case statement, i = -2`
4. `i++; // i = -1 here`
5. `i++; // i = 0 here`

**Hence :** value of `i` will always be `0` and will never be greater than `numbers.Length` so loop will not terminate.

**Hence :** infinite loop -> Unity Crashes

Comment: Last thing because that will tell you why it crashed. And if would be more helpful if you post **actual** code instead of just a snippet.

Comment: last messages in log are tagged with "(this message is harmless)" and evrything else i rly dont understand

Comment: **yes it is inside try catch, and it is looped 32 times, can loop make it crash?** regarding this, I would like to see full code snippet including loops and everything else in the method

Comment: w8 do i need to give you premmission or smth?, I am first time using stack overflow...

Comment: Don't worry I have permisions. Please post relevant code in answer next time instead of providing zip file.

Comment: ahh ok sry; like I said, i am using this for first time, tnx for your advice :D!

Comment: I'm pleased to be helpful. Please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @Patrik You can't upvote since you don't have enough reputation but you should accept this answer since it solved your problem.